# How to output $true or $false literally?

Tags: powershell, file-io, boolean

I'm writing a PowerShell template system for which I've created a variable placeholder that I want to replace with the actual variable value.
Eg `<%$myvar%>` should be replaced with the `$myvar` value.

I'm struggling to find a way to output this to a file when the value is `$true` or `$false`.
As a workaround I substitute `$true` by 1 and `$false` by 0 but I wonder if it's doable to output them literally.

Here is the part of my code:

```
Get-Content myfile.ps1 | %{
    if ($_ -match '<%(.*)%>') { #replace variable placeholder with actual value
        $tag = $Matches[0]
        Write-Verbose "found variable placeholder: $tag"
        $variablename = $matches[1] -replace '^\$','' #remove $ char so we can use it in Get-Variable
        Write-Verbose "variablename: $variablename"
        [string]$newvalue = Get-Variable $variablename |
                            select -ExpandProperty value
        if ($newvalue.ToLower() -eq "true") {
            $newvalue = 1
        }
        if ($newvalue.ToLower() -eq "false") {
            $newvalue = 0
        }
        Write-Verbose "new-value: $newvalue"
        $newline = $_ -replace [Regex]::Escape($tag), $newvalue
        $newline | Out-File newfile.ps1 -Append
    }
```

NB: If you're interested you can find the link of this project in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381149/lo%C3%AFc-michel?tab=profile).

Comment: whats wrong with "`$true"?

Comment: this just break the code ...

Comment: how can a string break the code? rofl

Comment: I dont want to use double quotes here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem with your current approach is that a string with a value of `true` or `false` would be replaced with a `1` or `0` wouldn't it?

Also note that you're casting the value to string right away, which could mangle other values as well.

What you might want to do is first check that the value is a `[bool]`, and then if so, you can just add `$` to the string value:

```
$newvalue = Get-Variable $variablename -ValueOnly
if ($newvalue -is [bool]) {
    $newvalue = "`$$newvalue"
}
```

Comment: Hoped this was the answer by it output `true` instead of `$true`

Comment: oups sorry forget to remove [string] cast. Works without. Great!

Comment: @LoïcMICHEL You could further simplify your code by changing the regexp to `<%$(.*)%>` so you could use `$matches[1]` directly instead of having to use an intermediate variable and remove the leading `$`.

Comment: Forgot to mention: you may also want to make the expression non-greedy (`.*?`), otherwise you may get unexpected results when putting more than one template expression in the same line.